# How to make space between LinearLayout children?

Tags: android

I am programatically adding custom views to a vertical LinearLayout, and I would like there to be some space between the views.  I have tried adding: setPadding(0, 1, 0, 1) to my CustomView constructor, but this doesn't seem to have any effect.  Any advice?

*It was pointed out that I should use margins.  Since I am dynamically adding views, I need to set the margins from code (not in xml).  I believe the way to do this is below, but it isn't working.

```
public class MyView extends View
{
    public MyView (Context context)
    {
        super(context);

        MarginLayoutParams params = new MarginLayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,  LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.setMargins(0, 10, 0, 10);
        setLayoutParams(params);
```

*Edit.  I also tried using MarginLayoutParams as a parameter while adding the views to the Linear layout (as below).  This also did not work:

```
MarginLayoutParams params = new MarginLayoutParams(linearLayout.getLayoutParams());
linearLayout.setMargins(0, 10, 0, 10);
linearLayout.addView(view, params);
```

Comment: It might help if you added the XML file to which you want to add the views.

Comment: Here's an excellent blog post about it: [Grid Spacing on Android by Cyril Mottier](http://cyrilmottier.com/2014/11/17/grid-spacing-on-android/)

Comment: a couple decades later, don't waste time, the answer is by @riwnodennyk below

Answer (score 171, accepted):

You should `android:layout_margin<Side>` on the children. Padding is internal.

Comment: You can define the view in XML with the desired margins and add the predefined views procedurally, applying the content in Java code as well.

Comment: I'm not really clear on what you mean by this.  I should define the customview in xml? But I will need to dynamically create an arbitrary number of custom views, which I will then add to my LinearLayout.

Comment: Try just using LayoutParams not MarginLayoutParams.

Comment: What attribute would I set in LinearLayout.LayoutParams?  That class doesn't seem to have "margins" or "padding" or anything similar?

Comment: @Thomas what do you mean by "Padding is internal". Should I be applying margin in each of the components, which I am kind of trying to avoid so as to minimize duplicate codes (as I have equal spacing to be used between my child components)

Comment: But it I margin_<side> is ignored if (child element's) height is `match_content`. That's why I came here. I'm confused

Comment: What does `android:layout_margin<Side>` mean? A little explanation?

Comment: @ataravati It means that you can follow `layout_margin` with the side where you want to apply it. Possibilities are: `Bottom`, `End`, `Horizontal`, `Left`, `Right`, `Start`, `Top` and `Vertical`. Eg: `layout_marginBottom`

Comment: @luismiguelss I misunderstood the OP's question. I was looking for a way to implement justify-between in a LinearLayout. I didn't realize the question was just for adding margin. Thanks!

Answer (score 254):

The **API >= 11** solution:

You can integrate the padding into divider. In case you were using none, just create a tall empty drawable and set it as `LinearLayout`'s divider:

```
    <LinearLayout
            android:showDividers="middle"
            android:divider="@drawable/empty_tall_divider"
...>...</LinearLayout>
```

empty_tall_divider.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <size
            android:height="40dp"
            android:width="0dp"/>
</shape>
```

Comment: You can use it on API<11 , if you use LinearLayoutCompat : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/LinearLayoutCompat.html

Comment: if you make the shape like a square, you can use it in vertical and horizontal LinearLayouts without the need to create a new one which has width.

Comment: Here's an excellent blog post about it: [Grid Spacing on Android by Cyril Mottier](http://cyrilmottier.com/2014/11/17/grid-spacing-on-android/)

Comment: This is much better if you have a set of views and turn some of them `GONE`. By specifying `android:showDividers="middle"`you'll only get the space where you actually need it.

Comment: @DariusL I cannot find this showDividers attribute in d.android.com, are you sure we can use this?

Comment: @Henry I am not certain, not developing Android right now. If it's deprecated, it should be marked as such in the IDE. It **was** an exposed attribute at some point. If you're not sure, you can programatically set it (setShowDividers()) or read the sources.

Comment: This solution doesn't support RTL

Comment: Note that this only works for horizontal layouts in LTR, RTL is broken. As a workaround for transparent dividers, you can set the dividers to show at the start, middle, and end then subtract the excess spacing at the start and end from elsewhere.

Comment: The only correct answer, after 2 decades  :)  thanks ...

Answer (score 42):

Android now supports adding a [Space](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Space.html) view between views. It's available from 4.0 ICS onwards.

Comment: Apparently the Android-Fairy listened to you and created a "Space" view in API 14 :)
(http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Space.html)

Comment: LOL!  It was only a matter of time.

Comment: but you need to at a space per view, which is not the same as declare a gap for all views.

Comment: ^ Very true.  However if you're using a LinearLayout, you can a add divider which will be applied to each child view. See here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html#setDividerPadding(int)

Comment: This isn't an answer.

Comment: If you use Space, and you remove/hide one of the children near it, the space is still shown, so this is a bad alternative to a divider, because it might take space that isn't between children.

Comment: @worked The divider padding is not a solution for the size of the divider, because it's on the opposite coordinates. Even in the docs you can see it. For example, if your LinearLayout has vertical orientation, the padding you get is on the LEFT and RIGHT sides of the dividers. Not above and below it.

Answer (score 26):

The sample below just does what you need programatically. I have used a fixed size of (140,398).

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(140, 398);
        layoutParams.setMargins(24, 0, 24, 0);
        layout.addView(button,layoutParams);
```

Comment: I was doing it with one more additional step like below  LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(140, 398);
        layoutParams.setMargins(24, 0, 24, 0); and then button1.setLayoutParams(layoutParams); layout.addView(button,layoutParams); .. Thanks for letting know that addview can take 2 arguments.

Answer (score 10):

Since API Level 14 you can just add a (transparent) divider drawable:

```
android:divider="@drawable/divider"
android:showDividers="middle"
```

and it will handle the rest for you!

Comment: Do you need to specify a divider drawable first or can you just use it with nothing else?

Comment: `8dp` where this came from?

Comment: @TimKist you can use it with nothing else I think

Comment: This answer is incorrect because android:dividerPadding does not affect the distance between linear layout children.  It applies padding to the sides of the divider that do not face the children (eg left and right padding on a divider in a vertical LinearLayout).  Android documentation: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html#setDividerPadding(int)

Comment: @leorleor You are right. The best way is probably to use a divider drawable which is transparent. I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: ... which means the answer to @TimKist 's question is now: No you cannot just use this with nothing else. When you add the line with "divider" in Android Studio it will ask  if you want to create a file. Do create one, then copy/paste the rectangle spacer from leorlor's comment above.

Comment: user changed name in the meantime I guess, the rectangle spacer should be the one in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18538656/540776)

Answer (score 6):

You just need to wrap items with linear layouts which have **layout_weight**. To have items horizontally separated, use this

```
<LinearLayout
    ...
    ...
  <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:gravity="center">

      // your item

  </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken the children need to have layout:width="match_parent" and layout_weight="x" (x is arbitrary, just needs to be the same.) 
You can then actually omit the layout_weight of the linear layout.

Answer (score 5):

Try to add **Space** widget after adding view like this:

```
layout.addView(view)
val space = Space(context)
space.minimumHeight = spaceInterval
layout.addView(space)
```

Answer (score 4):

Using padding in the layout of Child View.

layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_margin="5dp"
          android:background="@drawable/backage_text"
          android:textColor="#999999"
           >

</TextView>
```

backage_text.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <solid android:color="@color/white"/>
    <corners android:radius="2dp"/>
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#999999"/>
    <padding
        android:bottom="5dp"
        android:left="10dp"
        android:right="10dp"
        android:top="5dp" />
</shape>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` instead of `MarginLayoutParams`. [Here's](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html) the documentation.

Comment: What attribute would I set in LinearLayout.LayoutParams?  That class doesn't seem to have "margins" or "padding" or anything similar?

Comment: `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` extends `MarginLayoutParams` and it inherits the same `setMargins()` method you were using above...

Comment: Ohhhhh, thank you! I was looking at: android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams

Answer (score 3):

If you use [**ActionBarSherlock**](http://actionbarsherlock.com/), you can use com.actionbarsherlock.internal.widget.IcsLinearLayout :

```
<com.actionbarsherlock.internal.widget.IcsLinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:divider="@drawable/list_view_divider"
        android:dividerPadding="2dp"
        android:showDividers="middle" >
...
</com.actionbarsherlock.internal.widget.IcsLinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `android:layout_weight="1"`

Like This:
[image]

Comment: The question is about the vertical gap between the programmatically created views but your answer doesn't provide any solutions to that. You can review and improve your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the `LayoutParams` of parent `LinearLayout` and apply to the individual views this way:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
lp.setMargins(8,8,8,8);
```

- Take care that setMargins() take pixels as int data type.So, convert to dp before adding values
- Above code will set height and width to wrap_content. you can customise it.