# Adding a margin to ImageView programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a table layout where each row is built programmatically.

The structure is basically, for each row:

TextView, LinearLayout, LinearLayout, LinearLayout, Button.

Each of the LinearLayout has multiple ImageViews inside of them. I want to increase the spacing between the ImageView items as they render with their borders touching.

I tried the suggestions here - [In Android, how to make space between LinearLayout children?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4259467/in-android-how-to-make-space-between-linearlayout-children) - I create the parameters like so:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FillParent, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WrapContent);
```

And set it like this to an image view when adding the control:

```
linearLayout1.AddView(image1);
linearLayout1.AddView(image2, layoutParams);
linearLayout1.AddView(image3);
```

Note I am only setting it on the middle item as a left & right margin on this would be fine for what I am trying to achieve.

The problem is that even without setting any margins on the layout params i.e. just instantiating it and setting it as shown above, it adds about a 35px margin to the left causing a much larger margin than I wanted. Even calling SetMargins with 1px doesn't change the margin.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: try to set width wrapcontent.

(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WrapContent, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WrapContent)

Comment: @xitij Thanks. Please submit this as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set width of linear layout as WrapContent like this

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WrapContent, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WrapContent);
```