# Best practices for spacing between elements in LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I've created a simple `LinearLayout` with three identical elements:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Hello"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Hello"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Hello"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Now I'm going to introduce `8dp` space between each pair of elements.

Which solution of the ones below are considered as cleaner?

[image]
or:
[image]

or maybe some another?

Comment: What about using a view and place it between your views?

Comment: @MohammadZarei Do you mean solution described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18538656/1494902

Comment: I would suggest to go with the second one: you might want to change the `TextView` in some custom class in the future, and you can embed that in the class. Or you might want to create a `style` resource for that `TextView` and define margins in the `style`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Hello" />

<android.support.v4.widget.Space
    android:layout_width="8dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Hello" />

<android.support.v4.widget.Space
    android:layout_width="8dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Hello" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Add space to your code .

```
<android.support.v4.widget.Space
    android:layout_width="8dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Answer (score 5):

Either the given solutions, you can also use a drawable divider for `LinearLayout`

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:showDividers="middle"
    android:divider="@drawable/divider8p"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <!-- Your items here -->

</LinearLayout>
```

and for the divider declaration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#00FFFFFF"/>
    <size android:width="8dp" android:height="8dp"/>
</shape>
```

Answer (score 2):

I like the `Space` solution already posted, but I wanted to add another answer in the sprit of the original question.

In the case the OP presented, if I were to use margins to accomplish this, I would use start/left margin on each element other than the first. I would do this because of how I predict the layout might change in the future. It seems to me that the most likely thing to happen would be to add new elements to the end of the `LinearLayout` or to remove elements from the end of the `LinearLayout`. In these cases, if I'm using start/left margin on each item, I can delete individual views without having to touch the others.